# emberjs-RC2 render helper scope and action bubbling not allowing form to save

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

The **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GabSY/)**.

From the posts#index template, I can create a new comment by using the #linkTo helper which goes to the PostNewComment Route and renders the post/newcomment form. If I click  save the newly created comment is persisted using the 'save event' inside the PostNewComment Route.

You can uncomment the line below in post/comments" template, to see it working

{{#linkTo "post.newComment"}} Add comment{{/linkTo}}

I changed my UI to use a controller isAddingNew button and the render helper to determine When to display the form and now if I click the save button, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'one' of null
```

This how I render it:

```
<p> {{render "post.newComment" }} </p>
```

I suspect it is a scope issue because the error is only triggered when 'save' is clicked after using  the render helper.

To reach the 'add new comment' button:

```
   click  -> post -> a post title -> click comments link -> add comment
```

Is there a way to make the 'Post/newComment form' displayed via the 'render helper' in the post/comments template to use the 'save event' defined in the PostNewComment Route. 
Right now clicking on the 'save button' which is defined in that form goes directly to the parent route ie PostCommentsRoute instead of going to its own route probably because I displaying the form via the render helper.

I thought calling 'save' should go to its own controller and then bubble to its own route where it is actually defined, before attempting to bubble up the hierarchy to the PostComments Route.

Comment: Please to condense your question down to its essence. This is pretty rough to read. Also, I'm not sure your jsFiddle is functioning correctly. Clicking "Edit the Post" doesn't do anything. The bold in your question is also pretty hard to read... try using backticks instead of asterisks to wrap code.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for taking a look. The question has been condensed to its essence. I removed the edit route and edit template in order to keep the code concise to the just the part needed. I have added them back here http://jsfiddle.net/GabSY/3/.

Comment: Thank you! Have an answer for you shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a few alternatives, but this works and is pretty idiomatic: http://jsfiddle.net/GabSY/4/

In particular:

```
{{#if model}}
     <form {{action save content on='submit'}}> 
    {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="content.body" placeholder="body"}}
    <button type="submit"> save comment </button> 
     <button {{action cancel}}> Cancel</button>
    </form>
{{else}}
    <button  {{action open}}> Add comment </button>
{{/if}}
```

The reason you were getting the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'one' of null` error was that the `PostNewCommentController`'s model was never set. What I ended up doing was using the `open` action on the `PostNewCommentController` to set the `model` of the controller, which can be used in a Handlebars `{{if}}` to determine whether the form should be displayed or not.

I prefer this approach to the alternative of setting `content`/`model` (they are aliases to each other) of the `PostNewCommentController` from within the `PostCommentsRoute`'s `setupController` method because if you go down that route, it's easy to start mixing concerns between not-very-related controllers and routes. In my approach, all the logic for setting the `content`/`model` of the new comment takes place in the controller for new comments, which makes sense since a new comment no longer has its own route to initialize this data.

Comment: Many thanks for helping out just to clarify one thing.  I like this approach too but will it work assuming I apply same style to edit a comment that belongs to a post for the sake of coding style consistency on my side. I ask because I only moved the save event to the PostNewRoute because I could never get editing a comment to work, when I defined everything in the PostEditComment controller. So to have a consistent style I moved them to the route.

Comment: You use `partial` to share the form between the edit and new comments templates, and you could take some of the template code out of the `partial`. For instance, you could put your `if` statement only in the `newComment` template but obviously not put it in the edit comment template. I'm not sure what your plan is the for how comment editing works, but this approach/idiom can be bent to your needs.